# How to retrieve all of the records which dont have any reference in another table?

Tags: mysql

```
TableA 
id, name
1, abc
2, cde
3, def


TableB
id, TableA_id, topic
1, 1, blah 
2, 1, blah again
3, 2, abcdef
```

I want to select all of those records from TableA which dont have any references in TableB. How do I do it in Mysql?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use LEFT JOIN and select these records which don't have matching record in B.

```
SELECT
  TableA.*
FROM
  TableA
  LEFT JOIN
    TableB 
  ON
    TableB.TableA_id = TableA.id
WHERE
  TableB.id IS NULL
```

Comment: oh I was trying the left join but I missed the where clause .. thanks a lot for the answer.

Comment: The above works great and is quick, but the "opposite" query 'IS NOT NULL' i.e. find records that do join is very slow if tableB is massive, any ideas?

Comment: `IS NOT NULL` means simple `JOIN` (without `LEFT`). If it's slow I would check execution plan and check if there is matching index. Also -- do you need all columns from table B -- maybe reading them from disk makes the query slow?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TableA.*
FROM TableA
LEFT JOIN TableB ON (TableA.id = TableB.TableA_id)
WHERE TableB.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select a.*
From TableA a
Left Outer Join TableB b on b.TableA_id=a.id
Where b.id is NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT TableA_id FROM TableB)`